# Thinkpad W540 running ubuntu connected to an apple display using thunderbolt

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I'm wondering if there is some evidence that you can use an Apple Thunderbolt Display with a Lenovo that has a Thunderbolt port (W540 in my case) under Ubuntu.

Is there some driver needed or specific version or is this completely not supported.

EDIT :

I have installed Ubuntu (14.04) and try to use my Thunderbolt display without success. Once connected nothing happens and I don't know if the laptop is even aware that there is something connected into the thunderbolt port (I don't have any other tbolt peripherics). I try to update NVidia driver to the latest definition and was also not successful.

Comment: Do you already have the device? If yes, create a Ubuntu boot stick or DVD and try it out.

Comment: Sergio, any update? I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

My Lenovo W541 connects fine to one Apple Thunderbolt display, running both 15.04 and Win7. However, I can't get the daisychain to work...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, at least now I believe it's possible to have this setup working. I'll look to upgrade and try again.